# React Hydration - How can we hydrate a dynamic page that not fully available at build time?

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack, hydration, react-server

I am building a website using Express and React. I go with Server-side rendering
Now I am looking for a solution to hydrate my final HTML.
The issue is at the build time, the page is still not available. A page only started with a main component and Express middlewares can add/remove sub-components to that main component. It means we only know what is the final structure of the page at the end of the request

Is there any way I can hydrate that page and make React available in the client browser?

Thank you so much